# Installing ploty

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've just started to learn Python and have installed the redistribution WinPython. When I open the WinPython cmd and attempt to install the module ploty (pip install ploty), I get the following error:

"Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement ploty (from version : )
No matching distribution found for ploty"

What does this mean?

Comment: try conda install ploty?

Comment: i think you mean plotly

Comment: You are correct! I thought it was called ploty. Working now.